# Scraping Data From HTML File Using Java And JSoup - Android Studio

Tags: java, html, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping data from a local HTML page in Android Studio and instead of the right info being displayed all that its displaying is a blank screen. The info is not being taken from the HTML file(its not showing up in the log). Below is a the main piece of code. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.html"));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
            String str;
            while ((str=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str);
            }
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(buf.toString());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan='1']");
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            for (Element td : tableElements) {
                sb.append(td.text() + "\n");
                System.out.println(td.text());
            }
            textView.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Below is the HTML that i am trying to scrape. I want to scrape the times like "9:00" and "9:15". Also "Sound", "P.Mann","P2016","Ship","P2015","K.Lion" and "22-29, 32-36".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <title>timetable.html</title>
    <meta http-equiv='content-disposition', content='attachment;filename=timetable.html'>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/octet-stream" />

      <style>body {background-color:white;} body,td { font-family: arial; }            </style>
    </head>
    <data>
      <body>
        <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
          <col align='left' />
          <col align='center' />
          <col align='right' />
        </data>
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td/>
          <td/>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
        <col align='left' />
        <col align='center' />
        <col align='right' />
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td/>
          <td/>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
        <col align='left' />
        <col align='center' />
        <col align='right' />
        <tr>
          <td/>
          <td/>
          <td/>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%' >
        <col align='left' />
        <col align='center' />
        <col align='right' />
        <tr>

          <td>
            <table border='0' width='100%'>
              <tr>
                <td width='40%' align='left'  valign='middle'>
                  <font face='arial' size='3'>
                    <b>The Year<font size='1'>
                      </td>
                      <td width='20%' align='center' valign='middle'>
                        <font face='arial' size='1'>ICOM</td>
                        <td width='40%' align='right' valign='middle'>
                          <font face='arial' size='2'>
                            <b>Weeks selected for output: 26 (22 Feb 2016-28 Feb 2016)</td>
                          </td>
                          <td/>
                          <td/>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table  cellspacing='0'  border='1'>
                  <tr>
                    <td/>

                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>9:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>9:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>9:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>9:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>10:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>10:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>10:30</font>
                    </td> 
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>10:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>11:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>11:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>11:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>11:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>12:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>12:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>12:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>12:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>13:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>13:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>13:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>13:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>14:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>14:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>14:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>14:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>15:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>15:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>15:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>15:45</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>16:00</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>16:15</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>16:30</font>
                    </td>
                    <td   bgcolor='#C0C0C0' colspan='1'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>16:45</font>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr >
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" rowspan='1' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>Monday</font>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#FF0000'>Sound</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <col align='right' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000000'>P2016</font>
                          </td>
                          <td align='right'>
                            <font color='#008000'>P.Man</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;" >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='4' rowspan='1' >

                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#FF0000'>Ship</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <col align='right' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000000'>P2015</font>
                          </td>
                          <td align='right'>
                            <font color='#008000'>K.Loin</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr> 
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                    <td style="border-bottom:3px solid #000000;"  colspan='12' rowspan='1' >

                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#FF0000'>Mobility</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <col align='right' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000000'>P2222</font>
                          </td>
                          <td align='right'>
                            <font color='#008000'>D.Met</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      <table  cellspacing='0' border='0' width='100%'>
                        <col align='left' />
                        <tr>
                          <td align='left'>
                            <font color='#000080'>22-29, 32-36</font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your selectors to include "Sound", "P.Mann","P2016","Ship","P2015","K.Lion" and "22-29, 32-36":

```
Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan='1'],td[align='left'],td[align='right']");
```

Comment: But nothing is coming up, its to do with file part   '  InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.html"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);'   I added them in and it still comes up "false"

Comment: @DW41 does `buf.toString()` contain the expected value?

Comment: Dont think so , when i search for "Sound" in the log nothing comes up

Comment: @DW41 Can you try to print the value of `buf` to see what is its content?

Comment: i threw in " Log.d("String", buf.toString());" above Elements tableElements and all that im getting back in false from my app

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on *assumption* that since you didn't inform us about any error/exception related to accessing file *you can and are accessing it correctly*.

This means that problem may be related to

1. how you are parsing/selecting information from this file
2. how you are printing result information (but this point is out of my scope since I am not Android dev but I would assume that `textView.setText(sb.toString());` is correct step).

So I will focus on point 1. Only code related to searching part you are interested in is

```
Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan='1']");
```

If you take a look at examples from [tutorial](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) or [documentation of `Element#select`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) you will see that syntax for selecting element based on attribute is `element[attribute=value]` not `element[attribute='value']`.
So it doesn't use `'` nor `"` to describe value of attribute which means you don't need to surround `1` with `'1'`.

So change your code to

```
Elements tableElements = doc.select("td[colspan=1]");
```

Comment: About "*Also "Sound", "P.Mann","P2016","Ship","P2015","K.Lion" and "22-29, 32-36".*" I will leave it to you as practice.